# Manifest must be terminated by matching end tag

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hattrixz.fiz"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"/>
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
  <activity android:name=".VirtualTimeClockActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</manifest>
```

Nedless to say error will not let me debug.

So any help would be greatly appreciated

I also get the error "R" cannot be resolved in .java

```
package hattrixz.fiz;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class VirtualTimeClockActivity extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing application tag in your manifest.xml.  It should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hattrixz.fiz"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"/>
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
  <activity android:name=".VirtualTimeClockActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```